# R is a commutative ring with unity, let R be an integral domain for which IJ = I∩J for all ideals of R then R is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I hope to get a hint for this one.

> Let $R$ be an integral domain for which $IJ = I∩J$ for all ideals of $R$. Then $R$ is a field.

Comment: Let $a\in R$, $a\ne 0$. Then set $I=J=(a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$IJ=I\cap J$ means that every prime ideal in $R$ is maximal. Then use $R[x]/(x)\cong R$.

Comment: I think the fact that every prime ideal is maximal itself forces $R$ to be a field…